# Binding a list/collection/IEnumerable of Model Class to a Data Grid and Selecting Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I can't seem to find this answer via searching and cannot connect to the dots from other examples to my scenario.

Using MVVM Pattern:

1. How do I bind my model class via ViewModel in my view to a listbox/datagrid?
2. How do I pick and choose which columns I want displayed?
3. Question 2 Followup: Can I pick and choose via the visual Studio UI properties, if yes, how?
4. If done with XAML, is there autocomplete with my model/viewmodel class?
5. Using Observable Collection, what's the correct way to implement?
6. What is the "preferred" XAML control(datagrid?, listbox?, etc )

I've simplified my example into this:
Model Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace TestListBinding.Models
{
    public class ProjectModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestListBinding.Models;

namespace TestListBinding.ViewModels
{
    public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        private ProjectModel _project;
        private ObservableCollection<ProjectModel> _projects;

        public ProjectViewModel()
        {
            _projects = new ObservableCollection<ProjectModel>();
            var proj = new ProjectModel();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                proj.Id = "ID" + i.ToString();
                proj.ProjectTitle = "Project " + i.ToString();
                proj.ProjectDetails = "Details about this: " + i.ToString();
                _projects.Add(proj);
                proj = new ProjectModel();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ProjectModel> Projects
        {
            get { return _projects; }
        }
    }
}
```

**The View Part:**

I know I need to have a `DataContext` for the view. Many examples show it being set in the code-behind(see below), and some example reference a "StaticResource" for a listbox. I've not found a way to setup the bindings via UI with the way my code is setup.

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TestListBinding.ViewModels;

namespace TestListBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ProjectViewModel();//is this correct, or is there an alternative method via XAML/control properties?
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML(via code or UI) Can you please help me complete the data grid columns/bindings:**
Updated per @EdPlunkett

```
    <Window x:Class="TestListBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestListBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="239" Margin="42,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="435" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Title" Binding="{Binding ProjectTitle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project Details" Binding="{Binding ProjectDetails}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This yields a strange layout with extra columns:
[image: Extra Columns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct in your window constructor:

```
DataContext = new ProjectViewModel();
```

And this should show you some stuff in the grid:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="ID"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProjectTitle}" Header="Project Title" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProjectDetails}" Header="Project Details" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

WPF people generally don’t use the designer/Properties pane stuff. It’s not great and it hasn’t improved in over ten years. You’re out of luck on autocomplete in this case as well.

Preferred control? Depends what you want: If you want multiple columns per row, use DataGrid or ListView. If you want one value displayed per row, or some kind of pretty templated UI per row, use ListBox.

Quick ListBox:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource=“{Binding Projects}”
    DisplayMemberPath=“ProjectTitle”
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed resposne. I've updated the XAML code per your comments and added a screenshot. Shockingly, I'm getting more columns than what's specified. Also, for this example, I've bypassed my Database layer which would ideally be updated back and forth between the view and database.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to say, set AutoGenerateColumns=“False” on the DataGrid. Sounds like you do want a DataGrid, and the project class to be a proper viewmodel.

Comment: That fixed it! ...How do I trigger a change in a cell/grid value back to the viewmodel?

Comment: The grid will update the viewmodel property via the binding.

Comment: Does it raise an event? Do I need to subscribe to it? Can you explain?(I've changed Projects Property to `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Type in the grid cell, hit tab or return, and the vm property gets updated. Nothing to it. Put a breakpoint in the property setter on the vm and it’ll get hit. If you want your own code to do something in response to vm properties getting set, your main viewmodel can handle the PropertyChanged events of all the project vms. This is where we start wanting a VM, not a plain model.

Comment: Thanks. I put a break point on the setter of the Projects property and it doesn't seem to get hit when I change a value. Is there some setting I need to add to the datagrid in the XAML?

Comment: What made you imagine that the DataGrid will replace the entire collection just because you changed one property of one item in the collection? What sense does that make? Put the breakpoint in the setter of the property you are changing. If you change ProjectModel.ProjectTitle, put a breakpoint in the setter for ProjectModel.ProjectTitle.

Comment: I understand...partly, but I must be missing something in my VM. The datagrid is bound to the ObservableCollection and they're saying that they are always in sync. The columns/rows are bound to objects in the collection. I need another property which links to the edited property in the grid?

Comment: I can’t parse any of that. Who’s saying what’s always in sync with what, and what does that mean in concrete terms? What is “another property which links to the edited property”? “Link”? Show me code to “link a property”. I don’t know what that means. Or just write a normal viewmodel and bind the properties as I showed you.

Comment: This is very very simple. What about that breakpoint? What happened when you put the breakpoint in the right setter?

Comment: I must be missing something. Here's the latest xml: https://pastebin.com/Smd1kdRp and VM Class: https://pastebin.com/Kim629pB

Comment: If you don’t answer my last question, I will delete my answer and stop helping you. You’re not even telling me what’s wrong. You’re asking me to guess what your problem is. This is not a productive use of my time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193671/discussion-between-gismofx-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: I've put a breakpoint on the PorjectModel class's setters and I hit the breakpoint there. Isn't the point to keep the logic in the viewmodel class? Aren't I supposed to catch that action/change in the viewmodel before it hit's the model? I'll submit another question.

Comment: Read what I told you. All of it.